# generating report in ms access

Tags: ms-access, report

I am using a query to fetch data in ms access. I'd like to print the data using a report, but with the constraint that it must be two column per page, how do i do this?

or if you could suggest how i executed a query in ms access and get the records returned by a query in code, so that i can make the report another way.

thanks
[image]

Comment: Check out page set-up in design view.

Comment: In what way does it not do what you want? That is where you can set up columns.

Comment: Regarding you comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567437/ Can you print a single column of pictures? Which version of Access are you using?

Comment: am using access 2007, plus that only the paths stored in the db are returned, i have to somehow load the pics when the report is generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Sorry, I'm too much of a n00b to use the comment function, so I'm sending this as an answer, even though it's not definitive)

The column trick could work:  You should only have one column of controls actually in the Design View of your report.  In design view, make sure you only have the Image1 controls (get rid of the Image2 ones) and then resize the report so that the white space is half the size of the printable area or less.  When you resize the report, you should grab the right edge of the white space and literally drag it towards the left margin.  Finally, set the report for 2 columns in Page Setup.

Access should automatically make the second column from what you have in the first column, and should update the controls with the relevant field contents.

You can make sure that the images get assigned correctly by setting the "Control Source" property of the image control and not setting the "Picture" property.  (Picture is just a direct link to a filename, but Control Source will read from a field and assign the different pictures to their appropriate places).

Good luck!