# whats the correct way to code VBA if statement with many clauses (thousands)

Tags: vba

coding in VBA and I have 5 variables each which may contain a value with 2300 different possibilities.

if any of these values are present, my function should make this known.

in my last case, there were only 4 variables with 30 possible values each and i used a rather long, but functional if statement.

running into issues with too many line continutatio

suggestions are welcome please

below is the previos code used when i had 4 variables and 30 cases each (one very long If then)

```
If input1 = "ANON" Or input1 = "XNYS" Or input1 = "NYSE" Or input1 = "NSDQ" _
Or input1 = "XNAS" Or input1 = "ARCX" Or input1 = "ARCA" Or input1 = "BATS" _
Or input1 = "NQBX" Or input1 = "XBOS" Or input1 = "YBAT" Or input1 = "BATY" _
Or input1 = "NQPX" Or input1 = "XPHL" Or input1 = "CINN" Or input1 = "XCIS" _
Or input1 = "CBSX" Or input1 = "AMEX" Or input1 = "XASE" Or input1 = "ECHX" _
Or input1 = "XCHI" Or input1 = "TSX" Or input1 = "XLON" Or input1 = "XISE" Or input1 = "XMID" Or _
    input2 = "ANON" Or input2 = "XNYS" Or input2 = "NYSE" Or input2 = "NSDQ" _
    Or input2 = "XNAS" Or input2 = "ARCX" Or input2 = "ARCA" Or input2 = "BATS" _
    Or input2 = "NQBX" Or input2 = "XBOS" Or input2 = "YBAT" Or input2 = "BATY" _
    Or input2 = "NQPX" Or input2 = "XPHL" Or input2 = "CINN" Or input2 = "XCIS" _
    Or input2 = "CBSX" Or input2 = "AMEX" Or input2 = "XASE" Or input2 = "ECHX" _
    Or input2 = "XCHI" Or input2 = "TSX" Or input2 = "XLON" Or input2 = "XISE" Or input2 = "XMID" Or _
        input3 = "ANON" Or input3 = "XNYS" Or input3 = "NYSE" Or input3 = "NSDQ" _
        Or input3 = "XNAS" Or input3 = "ARCX" Or input3 = "ARCA" Or input3 = "BATS" _
        Or input3 = "NQBX" Or input3 = "XBOS" Or input3 = "YBAT" Or input3 = "BATY" _
        Or input3 = "NQPX" Or input3 = "XPHL" Or input3 = "CINN" Or input3 = "XCIS" _
        Or input3 = "CBSX" Or input3 = "AMEX" Or input3 = "XASE" Or input3 = "ECHX" _
        Or input3 = "XCHI" Or input3 = "TSX" Or input3 = "XLON" Or input3 = "XISE" Or input3 = "XMID" Or _
            input4 = "ANON" Or input4 = "XNYS" Or input4 = "NYSE" Or input4 = "NSDQ" _
            Or input4 = "XNAS" Or input4 = "ARCX" Or input4 = "ARCA" Or input4 = "BATS" _
            Or input4 = "NQBX" Or input4 = "XBOS" Or input4 = "YBAT" Or input4 = "BATY" _
            Or input4 = "NQPX" Or input4 = "XPHL" Or input4 = "CINN" Or input4 = "XCIS" _
            Or input4 = "CBSX" Or input4 = "AMEX" Or input4 = "XASE" Or input4 = "ECHX" _
            Or input4 = "XCHI" Or input4 = "TSX" Or input4 = "XLON" Or input4 = "XISE" Or input4 = "XMID" Then
    bucket1 = "BUCKET #1"
Else
    bucket1 = " "

End If
```

Comment: Don't put all those values in code.  Put all of these values onto an Excel sheet, load the values into a Dictionary, and check `If dict.Exists(input1) Then` for your `bucket1` condition, where `dict` is the name of the Dictionary variable.

Comment: was trying to avoid a v look up scenario. working in an access database but i can brainstorm off that idea. thank you

Comment: If this is Access then put the data in a table and run a query. Substantially more readable and flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Use an arraylist from the `System.Collections` namespace:

```
With CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    .Add("ANON")
    .Add("XNYS")
    .Add("NYSE")
    .Add("NSDQ")
    '// etc... etc...

    If .Contains(input1) Or .Contains(input2) Or .Contains(input3) Or .Contains(input4) Then
        bucket1 = "BUCKET #1"
    Else
        Bucket1 = " "
    End If
End With
```

Comment: For kindness towards a potential developer having to maintain this code, please do not add the values like that; rather, run a query to the database (that will return the list of keys to add) and add them with a simple `For` loop :)

Comment: Didn't realise this was for Access when I wrote it but in that case your logic is completely correct (although personally, I'd do the whole thing as a query anyway!)

Comment: its a process we would like to be more on the automated side, thats why i went with vba, but running a query would be much easier, i agree

Comment: You can definitely automatize this process and the above answer shows perfectly how to do it dinamically. However, instead of .Add(key) manually one by one, I would run a query (via VBA, not via the database engine), store the results into a collection and then looping through the collection for adding the keys to the dictionary. Like that, you won't have to manually add/remove a label when this gets added/removed in the database, and all will be done in few lines of code.

Comment: Here's an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4567452/3111149) for @Chris to merge the above approach with the comfort of adding keys to the collection via a classic Recordset.

Comment: thank you very much i will experiment with this method

Answer (score 0):

as one of the variants

```
Sub test()
    Dim in1$, input1$

    in1 = "|ANON|XNYS|NYSE|NSDQ|XNAS|ARCX|ARCA|" & _
          "|BATS|NQBX|XBOS|YBAT|BATY|NQPX|XPHL|" & _
          "|CINN|XCIS|CBSX|AMEX|XASE|ECHX|XCHI|" & _
          "|TSX|XLON|XISE|XMID|"

    input1 = InputBox("Criteria ?")

    If in1 Like "*|" & UCase(input1) & "|*" Then MsgBox "This is just an example"
End Sub
```

also you can use `Scripting.Dictionary` with `exist`, or as already mentioned use an array

Answer (score 0):

My alternative:

```
Dim MyStr As Variant, bucket As String
MyStr = Array("ANON", "XNYS", "NYSE", "NSDQ", "XNAS", "ARCX", "ARCA", "BATS", "NQBX", "XBOS", "YBAT", "BATY", "NQPX", "XPHL", "CINN", "XCIS", "CBSX", "AMEX", "XASE", "ECHX", "XCHI", "TSX", "XLON", "XISE", "XMID")
bucket = " "
If Not InStr(1, Join(MyStr, ","), input1) + InStr(1, Join(MyStr, ","), input2) + InStr(1, Join(MyStr, ","), input3) + InStr(1, Join(MyStr, ","), input4) = 0 Then bucket = "Bucket #1"
```

Convert the array to a string and check for the existence of the four inputs, if any are found set the bucket