# advanced execution of a query in ms-access in VBA code

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

My current VBA code is exporting my query to csv.

For quantity field, query criteria is [QuantityOrderedOriginal]-[QuantityShipped]-[QuantityBackordered]

Is there aynway in my VBA code, when the [QuantityBackordered] is not 0, import the [QuantityBackordered] field value instead?

My reference : [How to execute a query in ms-access in VBA code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567437/how-to-execute-a-query-in-ms-access-in-vba-code)

Comment: look at using IF in the query https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms182717.aspx or IIF in access https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into [using IF in the query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms182717.aspx), or [using IIF in Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d(v=vs.90).aspx).